# How to validate for big integer max value

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

I want to active record validate for big integer max value 9223372036854775807
but it can't validate

```
validates_numericality_of :amount, presence: true, :length => 4, :allow_blank => false, :only_integer => true, :greater_than => 0,  :less_than_or_equal_to => 9223372036854775807
```

Answer (score 0):

What does it mean, it doesn't validate?

Do you have any stacktrace?

You usually want to validate the value on creation, hence your code could look like this:

```
validates_numericality_of :amount, on: :create, presence: true, length: 4, allow_blank: false, only_integer: true, greater_than: 0,  less_than_or_equal_to: 9223372036854775807
```

Comment: You'd want to check that on update, as well.